# Can't get value from array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to output the value of the email value of an array, but have problems doing so.
The array is based on json_decode()

This is the error I receive

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/.... line 57
```

JSON (value of: $this->bck_content)

```
{"email":"test@email.com","membership_id":"0","fname":"Kenneth","lname":"Poulsen","userlevel":"1","created":"2012-04-23 10:57:45","lastlogin":"2012-04-23 10:58:52","active":"y"}
```

My code

```
    # Display requested user details
    $details_array = json_decode($this->bck_content);

    $value = $details_array['email'];
    print $value;
```

Comment: Is this code being executed in a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the second argument to `json_decode` to force array structures on JS objects.

```
json_decode($this->bck_content, true);
```

This will make sure all JS objects in the json are decoded as associative arrays instead of PHP StdObjects.

Of course that is assuming you want to use array notation to access them. If you're fine with using object notation then you can just use:

```
$value = $details_array->email;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, have been trying to find that error for at least an hour (probably closer to 2) :p

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$value = $details_array->email;
```

or

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

or

```
$details_array = (array)json_decode($json);
```

what have you done wrong is writen in error description